# Manually redirect stdin to a file during execution

Tags: c, clion

I need to be able to debug and redirect input to stdin in CLion, but I can't find a way to do this. The only solution I can think of is to set stdin to be the file.

I looked into using freopen() but this seems to be invalid in C99, which I have to use for the class I'm in.

Comment: Although I don't really understand what you mean, give a look at [dup2](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html), it may help

Comment: I need to be able to do the command ./program.out < input.txt (like you can do normally by CD into the cmake-build-debug folder, but this doesn't work for debug. The idea is to set stdin to a file manually instead of redirecting input via. the terminal, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

don't read `stdin` in your program

```
FILE *input = stdin;
if (debugging) input = fopen("somefile", "r");
// ... use `input`, not `stdin`
if (debugging) fclose(input);
```

Comment: The following works: freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin); but when I use fgetc() from debug, a value of -1 is returned, and I believe that means it isn't able to get a valid value from the file (the file IS valid). Everything else works fine when I run it with redirected input from the console (./program.out < input.txt)